# iOS WebView Youtube inline-Video

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, ios7.1, youtube-iframe-api

I want to play an youtube-video inline inside a WebView in an iPhone App.
In the youtube iframe-api I use the parameter "'playsinline': 1". 
When I inspect the video-tag inside safari devtools, in the video-tag the

```
webkit-playsinline
```

attribute is set correctly (...but the value is missing). 
 
Anyhow, the video plays not inline, but still switches to Quicktime. 
Though, when I execute

```
document.getElementsByClassName('html5-main-video')[0].setAttribute('webkit-playsinline','1')
```

via the Safari devtools in the context of the youtube iframe, it looks like:

```
webkit-playsinline=1
```

and the video is finally played inline.
Now I am wondering if this is a bug, and if there is a workaround to inject JS into the youtube *iframe* from a method of the Webview, like it is possible with Safari Devtools.

Comment: Thank you for this... I was missing the attribute alltogether although I set playslinline: 1.. I have another problem though, I want to be able to do this in Safari itself, is it possible (so not Webview but rather Safari)?